# How can convert UIKIT HTML Framework Date-picker component to Jalali Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, momentjs, getuikit

I use UIKIT HTML Framework on My project and I have a big problem with that, [UIKIT Datepicker](http://getuikit.com/docs/datepicker.html) component use moment.js Library for config time & date but I need to convert Datepicker's date to Jalali(Shamsi, Persian) Date. I'm searching and find [Moment-Jalali](https://github.com/jalaali/moment-jalaali) plugin on the GitHub but unfortunately, I couldn't figure out how can overwrite UIKIT Datepicker !!! :( . can you help me ?